# Балансировка АВЛ дерева

Tags: c, стек, балансировка

Такая проблема: при балансировке дерева использую поле глубины узла в структуре, но это неэффективно по памяти. Как можно определять фактор баланса в самой функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так ведь суть AVL в том, что хранение глубины (точнее, пары бит на [разность глубин](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE#.D0.90.D0.92.D0.9B-.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.BE_.D1.81_O.281.29_.D0.B1.D0.B8.D1.82_.D0.B2_.D0.BA.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.BC_.D1.83.D0.B7.D0.BB.D0.B5)) позволяет просто и эффективно выравнивать баланс при всех операциях.

Если же рассчитывать баланс в узлах на каждой операции, это приведёт к дополнительным затратам времени. Вместо `O(logN)` вставка или удаление будет занимать `O(log^2N)`